# (debug) awk to print column error for csv files

Tags: awk

i want to print the last columns of the csv data if the score >=20.

it should be very easy to use the code like (i have done similar work for many times and never showed error)

```
awk -F"," '$NF>=20 {print}' test1.csv > t1.txt
```

However.... in this dataset, when i used the code, i get the outputs like

```
> chr6 110079 110079 G A intergenic 3.711 
> chr6 143944 143944 G A ncRNA_intronic 4.929
```

the last column with value <20 were also printed.

any suggestions?

I have uploaded the test csv on this web: (will only available for two days) https://expirebox.com/download/abd5e34203602585557a3857f1b28620.html

Comment: It works for me..

Comment: What OS? I am using Mac.

Comment: Linux, with GNU awk.

Comment: @user2669497, please show sample Input here in code tags, when I am hitting your link it is giving me 404.

Comment: This code will work for the example input. But I don’t know why not work on that particular CSV data. That is why I uploaded to an online web. Maybe try using another browser ？

Comment: @user2669497, try checking if you have carriage characters in your Input_file? by doing `cat -v Input_file` and let me know on same then.

Comment: i have tested using Linux (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64)), it worked @randomir, but i don't know why not working on macOS seirrea.  i also tested using cat -v, only the last row  chr6,171053361,171053361,G,A,intergenic,0.713^M ----
chr6,171053514,171053514,G,A,intergenic,7.183
don't have the ^M.

Comment: Finally, the problem was solved using awk in unix, but i don't know why not working on macOS

Comment: Please post sample data directly to the question rather than using an external link (especially an expiring external link!)  The output you posted lacks commas and would not have been printed by your code (in those cases, `$NF` evaluates to `1`).